# If $X_i$ follows $ U( \theta, \theta+1)$ and n is even. How do I find the probability distribution of median?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics, marginal-distribution

> I have used the following transformation to find the joint pdf: $u= X_\frac{n}{2}$ and $ v = \frac{X_\frac{n}{2}+X_{\frac{n}{2}+1}}{2}$

> The joint pdf I have found is like below:
> $f_{(U,V)}(u,v)= \frac{2n!}{(\frac{n}{2}-1)!*(\frac{n}{2}-1)!}(u-\theta)^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(\theta+1-2v+u)^{\frac{n}{2}-1}$ and the support for **u** , **v** is $\theta<u<\theta+1$ and $u<v<\frac{u+\theta+1}{2}$

> I am trying to integrate the joint pdf with respect to **u** to obtain the marginal pdf of **v=Median**. But things are getting complicated. How should I approach this problem. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:** A simulation illustrates the approximate
shape of the density function of the median--in the
special case $n = 10, \theta = 5.$

```
set.seed(303)
h = replicate(10^5, median(runif(10, 5,6)))
hist(h, prob=T, ylim=c(0,3), col="skyblue2", 
     main="n=10: Dist'n of Medians of Uniform Data")
 curve(dnorm(x, mean(h), sd(h)), add=T, lwd=2, col="orange")
```

[image]

There is a ['Central Limit Theorem for Medians'](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554340/what-are-some-approaches-to-estimating-at-which-percentile-a-value-falls-given-l/2554650#2554650). It requires
that the population density be positive at the population median ($f(5.5)>0$ in my example).

In my example, $n = 10$ is yields sample medians that
are 'nearly' normal, but the fit it not perfect.
If you run the simulation with $n = 100,$ you'll get
a better fit to normal.

Ref: The [Irwin-Hall
distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) may be relevant.